# Why does the kv file return different value of the py file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

In my kv file a button size receives its texture size, when I print the size with the kv file it returns the real size but when I print with the py file it returns a different value. Why?

It's my kv file code, it prints [87, 25]:

```
<Base_P_Brick>:
    background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
    markup: True
    size_hint: (None, None)
    size: (self.texture_size[0], 25)
    on_press:
        self.abrir()
        print(self.size)
```

It's my py file code, it prints [0, 25]:

```
class Base_P_Brick(Button):
    def __init__(self, palavra, **kw):
        super().__init__(**kw)
        self.text = palavra.replace('\n', '')
        self.font_size = '20sp'
        print(self.size)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include the code as it's pretty difficult to answer your question without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an `__init__()` method, the `size` of a widget has not yet been assigned, so your `print` is just printing the default initial size of any widget (which is probably `(100,100)`).

You can add a method to your `Base_P_Brick` class that will report the `size` whenever it changes. Something like this:

```
class Base_P_Brick(Button):
    def on_size(self, instance, new_size):
        print('on_size:', instance, new_size)
```

Comment: So how can I do to take the true value in the py file?

Comment: Use `self.size` in a method that is not `__init__()` and is not called by `__init__()`.

Comment: I created a property that returns the size and I printed it after the class initialization and didn't work

Comment: See updated answer.